# Вопросительный знак

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста. В некоторых местах при сокращении предложений, что, кстати, мне и не нравится, я хочу видеть полный текст заголовка, но появляется вопросительный знак. Где и в каком месте данный фрагмент можно удалить? Странные, конечно, разработчики, нафига запихивать в платные темы, всякую херню! Извините, подгорело. Спасибо.

Изображение:  http://prntscr.com/le8p5c

"Попробуйте вместо substr использовать mb_substr" - данный вариант не рабочий, если у Вас только эта идея, тогда увы. Верней, как не рабочий, просто нет данного фрагмента в functions.php.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85325/discussion-on-question-by-sergey-cheremisin--).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб что-то в системе сломалось. Не предлагала она мне уйти в чат.